# Programmatically inject header mini cart

Tags: checkout, blocks, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm trying to update my header mini cart dynamically by creating a new block, I've tried several ways including:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart',
    //'checkout/cart', // OR 'Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart'
    'minicart_content',
    array('template' => 'ajax/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')
);

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
//Release layout stream... lol... sounds fancy
$this->renderLayout();
```

And also

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart')->setTemplate('ajax/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml')->toHtml();
```

They always come back empty, I can get it to bring back static content fine. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

In your module/controller/CartController.php action (or another) :

```
$data["cart_sidebar"] = $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')
->setTemplate('checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml')
->addItemRender("default", "checkout/cart_item_renderer", "checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml")
->addItemRender("simple", "checkout/cart_item_renderer", "checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml")
->addItemRender("grouped", "checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped", "checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml")
 ->addItemRender("configurable", "checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable", "checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml")
 ->toHtml();
```

You can use json to serialize your data.

Then have just to put in your js :

```
jQuery(".block.block-cart").html(data.cart_sidebar);
```

If you want upgrade cart qty, serialize it too ;)

Comment: ;) to you too there partner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your controller as an action (which you'd then call via ajax)

```
public function getTopCartAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
        $block = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
        $html = $block->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type',
            'application/json')->setBody($this->_success($html));
        return $this;
    }
```

This would then use whatever layout.xml directive may have altered 'cart_sidebar' block definition, from any 3rd party modules.

I use the following (which is in a template file):

```
<script>
    var request = new Ajax.Request(
            '<?php echo mage::getUrl("*/cart/getTopCartQty") ?>',
            {
                method: 'get',
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                    var json = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                    var cartElm = $$('.top-link-cart')[0];
                    if(cartElm){
                        var updatedTopCart = cartElm.innerHTML.replace(/(\d+)/g, 
                        json.content);
                        cartElm.innerHTML = updatedTopCart;
                        cartElm.title = updatedTopCart;
                    }
                }
            }
    );
</script>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can get minicart HTML in a controller with:

```
public function yourAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $minicart = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('minicart_content')->toHtml();
    echo $minicart;
    return;
}
```

Then you can replace minicart HTML using jQuery or similar:

```
jQuery('#header-cart').html(RESPONSE);
```

Comment: This code only update minicart content. But what about if I want to update mini cart qty as well which display beside cart?