# quick view add to cart in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, ajax, mini-cart

my module etc/modules/Minicart_Quick.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Minicart_Quick>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Minicart_Quick>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Minicart/Quick/etc/config.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Minicart_Quick>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Minicart_Quick>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Minicart_Quick</module>
                 <frontName>Quick</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Minicart/Quick/controllers/minicartcontroller.php

```
    <?php
class Minicart_Custom_minicartcontroller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function add_to_minicart()
{
    Mage::log("control get",null,"mini.log");
    $this->loadLayout();
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $block = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
    $html = $block->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type',
        'application/json')->setBody($this->_success($html));
    return $this;
}
}
```

Ajax function

```
function minicartAjax(){
var url = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('quick/controllers/add_to_minicart');?>";
alert(url);
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        //Your minicart html
        alert("hii");
    }
});
```

}

this is my updated code it's not working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your controller

```
public function <Your-Action>()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
    $block = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
    $html = $block->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type',
        'application/json')->setBody($this->_success($html));
    return $this;
}
```

in your ajax success part

```
if(data.status=="SUCCESS"){
    jQuery("#success_message").html(data.message);
    minicartAjax();
    var qty = jQuery("#qty").val();
    var curqty = jQuery(".header-minicart .count").html();
    var newqty=parseInt(qty)+parseInt(curqty);
    jQuery(".header-minicart .count").html(newqty);
    //jQuery(".header-minicart .label").html('Cart ('+newqty+')');
}
```

new function

```
function minicartAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: <CustomController-Action-Url>,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            //Your minicart html
        }
    });
}
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/52676/45103)

Find [tutorial](https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html) to create custom module-controller

Comment: can you explain it for me that can i add my action as "addtocart"  as same in script function name and also in core file where this controller located

Comment: just create new controller and after success in ajax just call that action and get this data because alter the core code is not good practice @Amith

Comment: so i can create a controller like this /app/code/local/name/name/controllers/CartController.php  ?? is this work out for minicart product updation without reload page

Comment: @Amith find my updated answer

Comment: how to get the custom controller url controller is located in "app/code/local/Minicart/Quick/controllers/minicartcontroller.php" and my action name is "add_to_minicart" i have tried to access the code like this "<?php echo $this->getUrl('Quick/controllers/add_to_minicart');?>" is this correct

Comment: `$this->getUrl('ROUT_NAME/CONTROLLER_NAME/ACTION_NAME');` @Amith

Comment: `$this->getUrl('quick/minicart/add_to_minicart');` if your rout name is quick in config file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55466/discussion-between-amith-and-gopal-patel).

Comment: @ Gopal Patel  please check the updated code